# How to check equality of two FStar.Set's

Tags: functional-programming, formal-verification, fstar

How can you check whether two sets are equal in FStar? The following expression is of type `Type0` not `Tot Prims.bool` so I'm not sure how to use it to determine if the sets are equal (for example in a conditional). Is there a different function that should be used instead of `Set.equal`?

```
Set.equal (Set.as_set [1; 2; 3]) Set.empty
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sets defined in `FStar.Set` are using functions as representation.
Therefore, a set `s` of integers for instance, is nothing else than a function mapping integers to booleans.
For instance, the set `{1, 2}` is represented as the following function:

```ml
// {1, 2}
fun x -> if x = 1 then true
         else (
            if x = 2 then true
            else false 
         )
```

You can add/remove value (that is, crafting a new lambda), or asks for a value being a member (that is, applying the function).

However, when it comes to comparing two sets of type `T`, you're out of luck : for `s1` and `s2` two sets, `s1 = s2` means that for any value `x : T`, `s1 x = s2 x`. When the set of `T`'s inhabitants is inifinite, this is not computable.

**Solution** The function representation is not suitable for you. You should have a representation whose comparaison is computable. `FStar.OrdSet.fst` defines sets as lists: you should use that one instead.

Note that this `OrdSet` module requires a total order on the values held in the set. (If you want have set of non-ordered values, I [implemented that](https://github.com/W95Psp/FStarToyStaticAnalyser/blob/c8504f74a464c54e69ac6cf9e0dcd02f94368cb7/CSet.fst) a while ago, but it's a bit hacky...)